# How to create transparent pixels in photoshop CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, pixels

I want to create a .png icon with transparent pixels to show what is beneath.  How do I change the white pixels to be transparent using Adobe Photoshop CS4?

Comment: Can you edit your post and attach a screenshot of the image file in question? I am pretty sure I know what you are asking but a visual would be nice.

Comment: Not readily since I have to get the image hosted.  Basically, I have an icon with up arrow that is on a white background and I want a transparent background so that when over something, only the arrow part obscures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the background layer.

http://www.wiitalk.co.uk/forums/fan-art/15025-photoshop-simple-way-remove-background.html

Comment: It should be noted that you also can select to start with a completely transparent picture when creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the alpha channel.  Go to layers assistant, channels tab, select alpha.  white == opaque, black == transparent, anything else == in between.  If it's not there, you might have to create it in the layers menu.